# Django admin relation filter

Tags: django, django-admin

I am creating the admin page, using this model:

Model.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        mail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        NIF = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True, blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Office(models.Model):
        company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Main')
        dir = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Employee(models.Model):
        oficina = models.ForeignKey(Office)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        mail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Report(models.Model):
        employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
        problem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        finished = models.BooleanField()
```

I have a problem when i want to create a new ReportForm... there are a lot of Employees!
I want to filter before ask the employee in the admin page

First ask the company, when the company is indicated, ask the Office, and when the office is indicated select the employee.
It is possible to do this?

this is my Admin.py now:

```
class ReportForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fieldsets = [
                (None, {
                        'fields': ['employee', 'problem', 'finished']
                }),
        ]

admin.site.register(Report, ReportForm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependant.html) or [django-selectable](https://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.7.0/advanced.html#chained-selection) or [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) can do that.